# How to nest commands in -c option of vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to open `file` with the first line containing `foo` highlighted, for this I'm using the following command:

```
vim -c ":execute "normal! gg/foo\<cr>V"" file
```

Which gives me the output:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use 2 different kinds of quotation marks:

```
vim -c ':exe "norm! gg/foo\<cr>V"' test.txt
```

However, for your specific usecase it is even simpler:

```
vim -c ':1' -c '/foo/norm! V' test.txt
```